# What Bill Murray movie is on TV in "Lost in Translation"?

Tags: lost-in-translation

While zapping through Japanese TV channels in *Lost in Translation*, Bob Harris (Bill Murray) comes across a movie or TV show featuring himself. It doesn't appear to have been made for the movie, as Murray appears to be considerably younger. **What movie/TV show is it?**

Answer (score 8):

The [*Features* section](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0335266/movieconnections#features) in IMDB contains 3 movies and 2 TV shows. Excluding *Matthew's Best Hit TV*, where Bill Murray was a guest, but only for this film (so he wouldn't be young), only [Saturday Night Live](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072562) had him, so it must be this TV show.

Comment: Your source says "Matthew's Best Hit TV (2001) (TV Series) - Bill Murray is guest star for this show, only for this film."

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Yes, but as OP noticed Bill is considerably younger in the show he watches, so it can't be this one. However you're right that taking this into account my answer was not clear, I've edited it.